# How to extend Class::Multimethods::Pure to recognise Moose Roles?

Tags: perl, moose, multimethod

I need multemethod dispatch with Moose objects. I'm doing this with [Class::Multimethods::Pure](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aMultimethods%3a%3aPure). I chose this instead of [MooseX::MultiMethods](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aMultiMethods) because it depends on [MooseX::Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aSignatures) which can't install on my system because it fails its tests. I don't mind if you have an alternative approach to suggest.

The following works fine with types and subtypes:

```
package Foo::Type;
use Moose;

package Foo::SubType;
use Moose;
extends 'Foo::Type';

package main;
use Class::Multimethods::Pure;

multi hello => ('Foo::Type') => sub {
    my ( $foo ) = @_;
    print $foo;
};

hello( Foo::SubType->new );
```

But the scenario I now need to handle is where the declared type is actually a Moose Role:

```
package Foo::Role;
use Moose::Role;

package Foo::Type;
use Moose;
with 'Foo::Role';

package main;
use Class::Multimethods::Pure;

multi hello => ('Foo') => sub {
    my ( $foo ) = @_;
    print $foo;
};

hello( Foo::Type->new );
```

But this can't recognise the role:

```
No method found for args (Foo::Type=HASH(0x22ac854))
```

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aMultimethods%3a%3aPure#Extending) says it can be extended in various ways, including adding Perl 6-ish roles. But it's a little sketchy for me and I'm looking for a more detailed example. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to convert the roles to abstract base classes using [MooseX::ABC](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aABC). In this way, they could be recognised as a class type.

On a side note, I managed to get MooseX::MultiMethods working on another system. It does work with roles, but it can't figure out which to use if we define a multimethod that takes the class and another multimethod that takes the role. Incidentally, MooseX::ABC resolved this issue also since it gave me a hierarchical structure which the roles did not really have.

```
package Foo::Role;
use Moose::Role;

package Foo::Type;
use Moose;
with 'Foo::Role';

package Merger;
use Moose;
use MooseX::MultiMethods;

multi method hello (Foo::Role $foo) {
    print 'Foo::Role: '.$foo;
}
multi method hello (Foo::Type $foo) {
    print 'Foo::Type: '.$foo;
}

package main;
my $merger = Merger->new;
my $f = Foo::Type->new;
$merger->hello( $f );
# Ambiguous match for multi method hello: (Foo::Role $foo), (Foo::Type $foo) 
# with value [ Merger{  }, Foo::Type{  } ]
```